# Positional argument error using rasterio to reduce raster pixel size

Tags: python, rasterio, resampling

I'm new with rasterio and I need to reduce the pixel size of a GeoTiff. Using the code below

```
def resample(input_raster: str, output_raster: str = None):
    upscale_factor = 2
    with rasterio.open(input_raster) as src:

        # resample data to target shape
        data = src.read(
            out_shape=(
                src.count,
                int(src.height * upscale_factor),
                int(src.width * upscale_factor)
            ),
            resampling=Resampling.bilinear
        )

        # scale image transform
        transform = src.transform * src.transform.scale(
            (src.width / data.shape[-1]),
            (src.height / data.shape[-2])
        )

        with rasterio.open(
            output_raster,
            "w",
            driver='GTiff',
            height=data.shape[2],
            width=data.shape[1],
            count=1,
            dtype=src.dtypes[0],
            crs=src.crs,
            transform=transform,
        ) as dest:
            print(dest)
            dest.write(1, data)
```

I see this error:

> test_raster.py:28 (test_resample) tmp_path =
> PosixPath('/tmp/pytest-of-maxdragonheart/pytest-0/test_resample0')
>
> ```
> def test_resample(tmp_path: Path) -> None:
>     output_data = str(tmp_path / "resampled.tif")
>
>    resample(
>         input_raster=input_raster,
>         output_raster=output_data
>     )
> ```
>
> test_raster.py:32:
> _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _  ../../raster.py:123: in resample
> dest.write(1, data)
>
> ---
>
> ??? E   rasterio.errors.InvalidArrayError: Positional argument arr must be an array-like object
>
> rasterio/_io.pyx:1338: InvalidArrayError

How I can solve?

Comment: Posting the full traceback would be helpful

Comment: Ok @mikewatt I do this

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have the output band index and array arguments swapped.

Try changing this:

```
dest.write(1, data)
```

to this:

```
dest.write(data, 1)
```

Comment: Unfortunately now I have this error `ValueError: Source shape (1, 1, 334, 414) is inconsistent with given indexes 1`

Comment: Slice/`np.squeeze` off those unnecessary axes.  Perhaps if you exclude `src.count` from the `out_shape` in your `read()` call that wouldn't be necessary

Comment: Nothing is changed @mikewatt However I've used this example https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/resampling.html